# Pyside Brew install error

Tags: python-3.x, pyside

I'm on osx 10.11.6, and I can't install pyside. I've tried:

```
brew install pyside --with-python3(the formula has been migrated to the boneyard)

pip install PySide(error configuring shiboken)

pip3 install PySide(error configuring shiboken)
```

What else can I try?

thanks.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Brew: Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: pip: error: Error configuring shiboken

Comment: pip3: dosen't work at all, says wrong version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full output of the commands

Comment: Also, `brew search pyside` first. It's probably a Cask. Or download it yourself https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Binaries_MacOSX

Comment: try: `sudo pip3 install pyside`

Comment: tried both, they both ended up with the same error